# Using a full URL with Restangular

Tags: javascript, rest, angularjs, restangular

I like all of the functions of Restangular for AngularJS, except that I can't find (and it may not support) a way of just passing a full URL to it. I realize the benefit of the .one('something','someparam') but my issue is that I'm passed various URL strings, and I really don't want to have to split() them just to use Restangular.

Also, I know about the baseURL function; but these URLs I'm being passed don't necessarily derive from the same base path.

For example, I might have:

```
/us/en/product/17726
/us/es/products
/us/es/product/991A0
/ca/en/accounts
```

All I'm given are the Strings...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm the creator of Restangular.

You have 2 options to do that.

1) Creating scoped Restangulars with different BaseURLs in each case: https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#how-to-create-a-restangular-service-with-a-different-configuration-from-the-global-one

2) You can use it like `Restangular.all('us/en/').one('products', 1726)` or `Restangular.one('us/en/product', 1234)`

Hope it works for you :)

Comment: That's what I needed. I tried adding the full URL like Restangular.all('/us/en') and it gacked out on me. Must have been that leading slash.

Comment: Do you think it would be useful to add a feature that would allow someone to make a one-off request given a string URL so they don't have to process it, or create multiple scoped instances? One of the benefits of this over $resource is that multiple instances are not required for a single request...

Comment: Hey, I don't think how much helpfull it'd be. Using it as it's now is pretty similar as you can see because you can use this with URLs as well :).

Answer (score 11):

I needed to simply `GET` an absolute url and came across this question.

Here's how:

`Restangular.oneUrl('routeName', 'http://absolute.url').get();`

[restangular#restangular-methods](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#restangular-methods)

Comment: What does `routeName` do here?

Comment: @AlirezaMirian I don't have the source that was using this on hand, but if I remember correctly `routeName` essentially acts as GUID for Restangular routes. The object that is returned from `Restangular.oneUrl()` doesn't need to know about `routeName`. Not sure how `routeName` conflicts are handled...

Comment: Watch out: in this form the returned Restangular element has an invalid route, so put() and post() won't work

Comment: @itghisi This could cause confusion. If an element is returned, the route is valid but it may not support PUT and POST verbs.